# Send data from adapter to activity and getStringExtra() return null value in first clicking

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I tried to send data from adapter A to Activity A.
In adapter A I used `Intent.putExtra()` and it's success.
And in Activity A I used `getStringExtra()` to get the data. 
When I clicked an item , `the getStringExtra()` returns null value. But, when I don't close my app and click the same item again, I got the value.

This is Adapter A :

```
class AdapterA (private val daftarMeja: ArrayList<DaftarMeja.Meja>, private val clickListener: (DaftarMeja.Meja) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){

companion object {
    const val ID_MEJA = "idMeja"
    const val STATUS_MEJA = "statusMeja"
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return daftarMeja.size
}

fun updateData(dataBaru: ArrayList<DaftarMeja.Meja>) {
    daftarMeja.clear()
    daftarMeja.addAll(dataBaru)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

    val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_meja,parent,false)
    return PartViewHolder(cellForRow)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as PartViewHolder).bind(daftarMeja[position], clickListener)
}


inner class PartViewHolder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    fun bind(meja: DaftarMeja.Meja, clicklistener: (DaftarMeja.Meja) -> Unit){
        itemView.tv_table_name.text = meja.nama
        if(meja.status){
            itemView.container_table.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorTableAvailable)
            itemView.tv_table_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        else {
            itemView.container_table.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient)
            itemView.tv_table_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
        itemView.setOnClickListener {   
            val intent = Intent(itemView.context, ActivityA::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(ID_MEJA, meja.id)
            intent.putExtra(STATUS_MEJA, meja.status)
            itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

            clicklistener(meja)
        }

    }
}
```

}

To get the data in Activity A :

```
val idMeja = intent.getStringExtra(MejaAdapter.ID_MEJA)
```

When the item clicked :

```
private fun mejaItemClicked() {

    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I don't know where is the problem. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Are you taking Data in OnCreate() meythod .

Comment: Yeah. But it's not directly in OnCreate() method. Exactly, I put getStringExtra() in my method  retrofit post. I need that data to post it again to my database. So, If I don't get the data my post method will Error.

Answer (score 0):

1)In Activity onCreate() , this is the right mode to test Bundle

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras != null) 
{
  if (extras.containsKey("YOURNAMEPARAM")) 
   {....your assign}
}
```

2)Wend lanch a intent FIRST you put in extra of intent the value

```
 val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
 intent.putExtra("YOURNAMEPARAM",yourvalue);
 startActivity(intent)
```

3)**Make sure that the type of variable you are passing is consistent and use the "PUT" and the "GET"corresponding to the variable.**

4)**Make sure the activity is not already open, otherwise the onCreate () method will not be called and your getextra will not be re-evaluated.**